# Хранилище картинок. Как чистить.

Tags: хранилище, файлы, изображения

Вопрос бородатый и ответа однозначного я так и не нагуглил. Допустим есть хранилище картинок. Мусора там никогда не используемых хватает. Встаёт вопрос о чистке. 
Я сам могу предположить 2 варианта.

1) С использованием БД. Можно noSQL. Делаем проксю через php например, а она апает дату запроса в БД. Ну и через пол годика можно подчистить к которым запросов не было. Но я как представлю сколько это оверхеда на каждую картинку.... аж плохо становится)

2) Менять атрибут "дата создания", но опять же оверхед, но вроде меньше.

Есть ли более легкие решения?

Comment: я у себя реализовывал через last access time у файла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Средствами веб-сервера хорошо бы. Напр. раз в (день|неделю|месяц) парсить логи веб сервера, и на их основании определять забытые картинки. Это "легче", чем каждую отдавать через php.

Comment: А сколько хранить оные логи, тогда? Их тоже чистить нелишне.

Comment: Раз в сутки обработали логи - и логи стёрли. Я имею в виду, что скрипт на основе логов один раз в сутки обновляет даты для каждого файла в БД: (*имя_файла, timestamp*).

А другой процесс по расписанию, мусоросборщик, раз, скажем, в неделю, трёт файлы, те, что отсутствуют в выборке "недавнопрочитанных" их БД.

Comment: Раз в сутки это уже хорошо) Нужно додумывать в эту сторону....